# Dropzone JS add Remove Button

Tags: php, jquery, dropzone.js

Sorry im stil newbie from dropzone,
I need create Remove Button From Dropzone JS after file success Upload
i was tried using

```
if(typeof Dropzone != 'undefined')
        {

            Dropzone.autoDiscover = true;

            $(".dropzone[action]").each(function(i, el)
            {
                $(el).dropzone();
            });
            Dropzone.createElement("<button>Remove file</button>");     

        }
```

the remove button still not show on buttom of tumbnails.
my page :

```
<form action="data/upload-file.php" class="dropzone"></form>
```

my PHP UPLOAD File

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

#$errors = mt_rand(0,100)%2==0; // Random response (Demo Purpose)
$errors = false;


$resp = array(
);

# Normal Response Code
if(function_exists('http_response_code'))
    http_response_code(200);

# On Error
if($errors)
{
    if(function_exists('http_response_code'))
        http_response_code(400);

    $resp['error'] = "Couldn't upload file, reason: ~";
}

echo json_encode($resp);
```

Comment: DropzoneJs already have a remove file button. Did you enable `addRemoveLinks` option?

Comment: where i put the option code?

Comment: `if(typeof Dropzone != 'undefined')
  {
   Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
   Dropzone.addRemoveLinks = true;

   $(".dropzone[action]").each(function(i, el)
   {
    $(el).dropzone();
   });
  }
 };`

Comment: i try that still not show the remove button

Answer (score 5):

i was success thanks @pddong
by add "addRemoveLinks: true"

```
if(typeof Dropzone != 'undefined')
    {
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#myDropzone", {
        url: "data/upload-file.php",
        maxFileSize: 50,
        acceptedFiles: ".pdf",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        //more dropzone options here
    });

    }
};
```

and the page be like this

```
<form action="data/upload-file.php" class="dropzone" id="myDropzone"></form>
```